# How many CO2 is emitted (in kg) by using 1 m3 of LNG?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, materials

How much CO2 in kg is emitted by using 1 cubic meter of LNG? It is used for a dry booth after painting products.
Unfortunately, this is all information I have. Please note the assumptions for answering this question.

Comment: are you talking about *burning* LNG? And are you measuring a cubic metre of the gas or the liquid (as the product is often measured by the volume of the gas at STP not by the volume of the very cold liquid)?

Comment: Using LNG ( liquid natural gas) in small scale is quite unusual, as it demands cryogenic devices. I would expect rather LPG ( liquid propan/butan gas ) or PNG ( pressurized natural gas ).

Comment: STP (to simplify a little) means room temperature and pressure. The point being that LNG is normally distributed as a gas (it is basically the same as the natural gas distributed in domestic and industrial piped gas and consists mostly of methane). LNG is never delivered as a liquid to customers: it is *transported* as a liquid in very large refrigerated tankers but is regasified and injected into the normal gas pipelines used to distribute natural gas.

Comment: Also worth noting the possible confusion with LPG which consists mainly of propane or butane both of which can be liquefied by pressure alone and don't require cooling. This makes them *far* easier to transport efficiently in cylinders for small scale use.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will ask some additional questions to the user of this LNG.

Comment: @matt_black Thanks Matt. Using LNG for restored NG is quite confusing. As liquid nitrogen is frequently used e.g. in cryocenters, I have thought perhaps LNG can be delivered as well. But I would agree it would be a big security risk becoming a NG bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Density of gas, assuming ideal behaviour, is $\rho=\frac{pM}{RT}$ .

With assumption the natural gas is pure methane, burning follows the reaction:

$$\ce{CH4(g) + 2 O2(g) -> CO2(g) + 2 H2O(g)}$$

Therefore the mass of $\ce{CO2}$ created by burning $\pu{1 m3}$ of natural gas at $\pu{1 atm}$ and $\pu{25 ^{\circ}C}$ is

$$m_\ce{CO2} = \frac{pM_\ce{CH4}}{RT} \cdot V \cdot \frac{M_{\ce{CO2}}}{M_{\ce{CH4}}} =  \frac{p}{RT} \cdot V \cdot M_{\ce{CO2}}\approx \frac{\pu{e5 Pa} \cdot \pu{1 m3} \cdot \pu{0.044 kg/mol}}{\pu{8.314 JK-1mol-1} \cdot \pu{298 K}} \approx \pu{1.78 kg}\ \ce{CO2}$$